# How do I install track for sliding closet door on laminate

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood

How do I install track for sliding closet mirror doors on laminate floor

Answer (score 1):

Laminate flooring is made to move when needed, so screwing through to the subfloor under the laminate may not do the floor well. Since sliding doors do not exert a lot of pressure at the guides on the bottom, you could size the screw to only secure itself into the laminate itself, say no more than 1/2" long screws, considering the laminate should be about 3/8" thick, the mounting plate is about 1/16" thick and the pad under the flooring adds a little too. If the laminate flooring is 1/2" thick, like some are, then a 5/8" screw could be used. Using screws this small should be run in manually, not with a power tool.

To be sure everything moves as it should, you could set the guide completely then remove the screws, file just the sharp point of the screw off, about 1/16", then reset the screws.

Although the floor does move a bit, it should not affect the operation of the guide. If the floor does move enough to do so, more than a 1/2", then you have other issues to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just install wall plugs onto your floor, and leave spaces around the laminate board. I would presume that your laminate floor in your cupboard does not receive too much heat and sun variation (since its in the cupboard), hence movement would not be as much as those boards which receive direct sun.

So, to proceed, with a wood/steel bit, drill a larger hole into the laminate, then once you get near the floor stop and switch to a masonry bit which fits your wall plug.  then simply place the wall plug into hole and use the correct screws into the rail.